# How to reset input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reset the input field.

If I click "Type 1" radio button and enter value in input field and again if i select "Type 2" radio button then the existing value in the input field should be reset to empty.

```
<div class="samples">
    <input type="radio" id="samples_1" />Type1
        <input type="radio" id="samples_2" />Type2
            <input type="radio" id="samples_3" />Type3
</div>

<input type="text" id="demo" value=""/>
```

How can I implement this in javascript/jquery.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wYuZL/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wYuZL..here is the jsfiddle for the question

Comment: You should probably write some code. Try reading about the `$.click` event. The resetting can be done by using `$("#..").val("")` which sets the input field's value to blank("").

Comment: Can I have some example/demo since am newbie..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, it works. And you haven't added jquery - add jquery in jsfiddle to make it work.

```
 $(":radio").bind("change", function (event){
      $("#demo").val("");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I implement this in JavaScript/jQuery?

Assuming I understand what you're trying to do (make it so that when you click on the radio buttons, the value of the input box is cleared) then you will have to set an event handler on the elements so that we can clear the input box:

```
$(function() {
    $("#samples > input").click(function() {
        $("#demo").val("");
    });
});
```